# How to use msbuild to create csx output for Azure SDK 1.8?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-roles

I have a Visual Studio project with an Azure Cloud project that has one Web Role for a WCF Service. Rather than creating a cspkg by using the Package command in Visual Studio or with cspack, I need to create the same output that is in the project's csx folder with msbuild. However, if I run the following command in msbuild, the output doesn't have the same folder structure as the csx folder:

```
msbuild MyAzureProject.ccproj /p:configuration=debug /maxcpucount /p:outdir="c:\OutDir" /p:overwritereadonlyfiles=true /p:targetprofile="Cloud"
```

Instead it creates a _PublishedWebsites folder. Does anyone know how to create the contents of the csx folder manually by using the msbuild command-line (i.e. csx/roles/MyAzureRole/approot)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing the targets switch.

Here's what works for me.

msbuild MyAzureProject.ccproj /p:configuration=debug /maxcpucount /p:outdir="c:\OutDir" /p:overwritereadonlyfiles=true /p:targetprofile="Cloud" /target:Clean;Publish